# Is there a 3D table or 'column of columns' for only some columns in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to convert a simple 2D data frame with columns:

```
| A | B | C1 | C2 | C3 | D1 | D2 | D3 | E | F |
```

To something along the lines of

```
        |      C       |      D       |      
| A | B | C1 | C2 | C3 | D1 | D2 | D3 | E | F |
```

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html

Comment: @Alexander Oh perfect! thanks. Not sure why I could not find that in their Docs before.